# Initialize Array Of Object in Spring

Tags: java, arrays, spring, object

Student.java

```
package org.manan.student;

public class Student {
    String stName;
    int stId;

public String getStName() {
    return stName;
}
public void setStName(String stName) {
    this.stName = stName;
}
public int getStId() {
    return stId;
}
public void setStId(int stId) {
    this.stId = stId;
}}
```

MainApplication.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student[] student = new Student[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
        student[i] = new Student();
    }

}
```

Now my question is, how to initialize above student array in beans.xml file?

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="mainApplication" class="org.manan.main.MainApplication">
    <property name="student">
        <list>
            <ref bean="student" />
        </list> 
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="student" class="org.manan.student.Student">
</bean> 
</beans>
```

**In short, how to configure 
    Student[] student = new Student[3];
into Beans.xml file?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<bean id="student" class="org.manan.student.Student" scope="prototype"> </bean>
```

If you won't do it, the references will be to the same objects (singelton) 
And then just ref to it several times

```
<list> 
<ref bean="student" /> 
<ref bean="student" />
<ref bean="student" />
</list>
```

Comment: I mean how to declare & initialize array of Student object in Beans.xml?

Answer (score 0):

With `prototype` , each time you refer the bean, it will be new instance. By default it will be singleton and even you refer it multiple times, all three elements will contain same object

```
<bean id="mainApplication" class="org.manan.main.MainApplication">
    <property name="student">
        <list>
            <ref bean="student" />
            <ref bean="student" />
            <ref bean="student" />
        </list> 
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="student" class="org.manan.student.Student" scope="prototype">
</bean>
```

Comment: But what if I have to initialize 100 objects?

Comment: you have to refer it 100 times

Comment: But don't you think that is inefficient? There should have to be another way to do this

Comment: Go for spring factory method in this case

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? Because I'm new to spring

Comment: Also its not inefficient.Either you are doing it in loop or thru, JVM has to create 100 instances. so there will no noticeable difference in performance